# How to implement logic that processes conditions after a specific time has passed following an API call?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am building a service using Spring Boot, and it is a coffee chat service. I would like to automatically cancel a coffee chat request if the mentor does not accept it within 24 hours.

However, I am not sure of the exact method, so initially, at 11:59 PM, I have set up a batch processing as follows:

```java
@Scheduled(cron = "0 59 23 * * *")
public void updateAutoCancel() {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now()
            .toLocalDate()
            .atStartOfDay();
    List<Mentoring> waitingMentorings = mentoringGetService.byStatusAndCreatedAt(WAITING, now);
    waitingMentorings.forEach(mentoring -> {
        mentoringUpdateService.updateStatus(mentoring, CANCEL);
        Refuse refuse = RefuseMapper.mapToRefuse(mentoring);
        refuseSaveService.saveRefuse(refuse);
    });
}
```

Is periodically running a Timer every minute the best approach to ensure precise handling after exactly 24 hours? Are there any alternative methods?